# Resources not showing in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I have build an application which is having number of image file. When I am running the project in Simulator its been shown properly. But when I am trying to run in iPhone it is giving error

> "Could not find file:
>   /Users/wipro-mac1/Desktop/Work@ce/PleatcoApp/PleatcoApp/Resources/images/02-SEARCH-STORE-LOCATOR_03.png"

for every png files and images are not shown.

What should be the problem?

Comment: Maybe the image name's problem?

Answer (score 1):

> "Could not find file: /Users/wipro-mac1/Desktop/Work@ce/PleatcoApp/PleatcoApp/Resources/images/02-SEARCH-STORE-LOCATOR_03.png"

The fact that this error is appearing on iPhone, means  you've given a very bad path to load the image. `/Desktop/` for example does not exist on the iPhone file system.

You don't provide file paths to load resources in iOS, you add the files to the Application Bundle, then simply refer to them by name. For example, to load an image in code, you need to do the following:

1. Add the `.png` file to the project. Do this by dragging it in to Xcode, and adding it to your intended targets. (Typically the application name).

   You will get this screen, typically this should be OK for your needs.

   [image: Copied file into Xcode prompt]
2. In code, load it up using the following:

   ```
   [UIImage imageNamed:@"02-SEARCH-STORE-LOCATOR_03"];
   ```
3. Use the image how you see fit.

Without any code to see, I can't fully help solve the problem, but this is a good start.

Comment: @user1794696 If this answer satisfied your requirements, could you please accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a case sensitive filename error:

in simulator if you've got the file "aFile.png" and load it as "afile.png" it works fine

but on a device the file won't be found: iPhone/iPad are case sensitive